# A field of characteristic zero is perfect

Tags: field-theory

How do you prove that a field $F$ of characteristic zero is perfect, or rather that every irreducible $f(x)$ in $F[x]$ is separable?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean that every *irreducible* $f$ is separable?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, I shall edit the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is true because every irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ in $F[x]$ is separable (provided the characteristic of $F$ is zero, or $F^p=F$ for prime characteristic $p$). Indeed, we have $f'(x)\neq 0$ for the derivative, because $deg(f')=deg(f)-1$. Here we have used that a polynomial $f(x)$ is inseparable if and only if $f'(x)=0$.

Comment: Why is $f(x)$ inseparable $\Leftrightarrow f'(x)=0$? Shouldn't we say that $f(x)$ is inseparable $\Leftrightarrow \gcd(f(x),f'(x))\neq 1$?

Comment: @rmdmc89 See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1957209/if-derivative-of-an-irreducible-polynomial-is-non-zero-then-the-polynomial-is-se) or [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417612/separability-of-polynomials), Corollary  $3.4.3$ part $(2)$.